# using javascript to launch implicit intents on android

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, webview, implicit

In my app I generate an html dinamically to fill a webview and show info to the user.

this html has custom URLs with data to pass it to another activity via an implicit intent.
ie.

```
    <a href="com.somedata://1/some Text">
       some Text
    </a>
```

So I pass the data: **"1"** and: **"some Text"** to another activity. The activity who gets the intent recovers the data with

```
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
   List<String> segs = data.getPathSegments();
   //here I get the number:
   String number = data.getHost();
   //here I get the text:
   String text = segs.get(0);
```

It works great but. 
That forces my app to write the text twice. One in the **href="HereGoesData"** and other in the text itself to show it to the user in the webview

I wonder if there is a way to avoid this using javascript for dinamically create the URL for the intent.

So the script should wait for the user's click and recover the text and based on that create an URL to launch the intent with the info.

I don't know much about javascript but if it is possible I think this shouldn't be so hard to do.

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I did it.
It's not difficult actually for a non-newbie in javascript

first you have to change the  tag to call the function that builds the URL programatically using javascript:
instead of:

```
     <a href="com.somedata://1/some Text">
      some Text
  </a>
```

use:

```
   <a id="someID" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="buildUrl(this)">
      some Text
  </a>
```

So when you click on it executes the javascript function that builds the URL and launches the implicit intent:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function buildUrl(ele){
      var nodes = ele.childNodes;
      var a = nodes[1].textContent

      var url = "com.somedata://"

    window.location = url + 1 + "/" + a
     }
  </script>
```

And it's done
 tested and working.